# new "Only Connect" puzzle

Tags: wordplay, pattern, knowledge, connect-wall

Please be kind - this is my first puzzle!

```
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
|   alcohol  |    and    |    arrow   |     cat    |
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+  
|    cave    |   demon   |   federal  |  fireworks |  
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+  
|    guts    |   order   |    paper   |   prince   |
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
|  seedcake  |   stone   | toothbrush |    upon    |
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

The rules are as standard: divide these 16 words into 4 thematic groups of four.
Have fun - I did!

Comment: Great first puzzle! :D

Answer (score 6):

Got one!

> GUTS, SEEDCAKE, FEDERAL, UPON.
>
>  They all contain 3 consecutive letters of the alphabet backwards, namely STU, CDE, DEF, NOP.

This leaves:

> ```
>  +------------+-----------+------------+------------+
>  |   alcohol  |    and    |    arrow   |     cat    |
>  +------------+-----------+------------+------------+ 
>  |    cave    |   demon   |            |  fireworks | 
>  +------------+-----------+------------+------------+ 
>  |            |   order   |    paper   |   prince   |
>  +------------+-----------+------------+------------+
>  |            |   stone   | toothbrush |            |
>  +------------+-----------+------------+------------+
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Is this one?

> FIREWORKS, SEEDCAKE, TOOTHBRUSH, UPON.
>  Are all formed of two words stuck together.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another possible category, compatible with the one JonMark Perry found.

> AND, ORDER, PRINCE, STONE.
>
>  These are all words that occur in the titles of the Harry Potter books.

Taking this together with JonMark's answer, this leaves:

> ```
>  +------------+-----------+------------+------------+
>  |   alcohol  |           |    arrow   |     cat    |
>  +------------+-----------+------------+------------+ 
>  |    cave    |   demon   |            |  fireworks | 
>  +------------+-----------+------------+------------+ 
>  |            |           |    paper   |            |
>  +------------+-----------+------------+------------+
>  |            |           | toothbrush |            |
>  +------------+-----------+------------+------------+
> ```